# Is there a problem with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, miktex

A document that had been working recently will not work today and i narrowed the problem down to this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
d
\end{document}
```

If I cut the hyperref then it runs.  But this MWE gives an error message:

```
Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed.
```

And it produces an empty log file.  The log file is there, but has nothing in it.

By running pdflatex from the command line I get this:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty")
======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
visiting repository http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
repository type: remote package repository
loading package repository manifest...
downloading http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
0.20 MB, 4.52 Mbit/s
package repository digest: 19243c776ebfe07052e5d89f5bbfc793
going to download 990 bytes
going to install 3 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-latex.tar.lzma...
0.00 MB, 0.20 Mbit/s
extracting files from miktex-latex.tar.lzma...
======================================================================

Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
```

I have refreshed both the fndb and the font map files, in both user and admin modes.

My hyperref has been updated twice in the past ten days. The version I have now was packaged on 1/22/2020 and updated 1/28/2020.  It is possible that I have not used it since 1/22/2020 and very likely I have not tried to use the 1/28/2020 update until now.

I am using MiKTeX version 2.9.6809 in WinEdt 10 Build: 20180507  (v. 10.3) - 64-bit

Comment: I suggest updating Miktex via Miktex console. Your code does work on my computer

Comment: Compile once on the command line and show the log-file.

Comment: @BlackMild i always update via MiKTeX console.

Comment: but my first guess would be that you should update the package database in the menu tasks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, but I do not know how t compile on the command line.  The PDFTeXify button produces an empty log file.  Updating the package database in the menu tasks did not change anything.

Comment: don't use the pdftexify button. texify is a pain when there are errors. Try only pdflatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  That is good to know, but in this case I just tried it and it makes no difference.

Comment: The error message should be different. Go to the windows explorer, to your document folder. Type `cmd` in the address bar of the explorer and hit enter. This should open a command line. There type `pdflatex name-of-your-file` and hit enter. Show the output.

Comment: miktex is trying to find hyperref.cfg which no longer exists. This mean that you did **not** update the package database. Do it in admin mode and user mode in the miktex console in the menu tasks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  MiKTeX believed hyperrref was updated, so I uninstalled it, reinstalled, and (for good measure) ran all three update commands in both user and admin mode.  Now it works!